# iOS Autolayout how to stretch out subview in superview

Tags: ios, xcode6, autolayout, ios-autolayout

[image]

As you can see on the screenshot here is gray `UIView` which I use as a container. In the code I allocate a `UINavigationController` and add it's view as a subview to the gray container view. The `UINavigationController` has `RootViewController` (you can see the cut off table view on the left side - it is my root view controller of UINavigationController).

My question is how to pin all sides to the superview bounds. Because right now I just can see a part of the `RootViewController` view.

In the storyboard I have set all constraints as for gray container view as for `RootViewController` view of `UINavigationController`. If I normally `PushViewController` instead of adding as a subview it shows without cut off issue.

Here is a code I have in `UIViewController` that contains gray container view:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

    if (self)
    {
         KNCouponsViewController *couponsViewControllerByList = [KNInstantiateHelper instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"KNCouponsViewController"];

        self.theNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:couponsViewControllerByList];

    }

    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.theContainerView addSubview:self.theNavigationController.view];
}
```

Here is constraints for the gray container view

[image]

Here is constraints for the view of root view controller which has cut off table:

[image]

Seems like a simple solution is to set `UINavigationController` view the same width and hight as the gray container has:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGRect rect = self.theContainerView.frame;
    rect.origin.x = 0;
    rect.origin.y = 0;

    [self.theNavigationController.view setFrame:rect];

    [self.theContainerView addSubview:self.theNavigationController.view];
}
```

Then it works correct. But I think if we will not modify a frame only then it will work?

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways.

- 1 way is to call `addSubView` code in `viewDidLayoutSubview` method
- 2nd way is to use following code for settings frame

  [self.theContainerView addSubview:self.theNavigationController.view];
  [self.theNavigationController.view setFrame: self.theContainerView.frame];

Note: If you use first way then add your code in

```
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
[self.theContainerView addSubview:self.theNavigationController.view];
[self.containerView layoutIfNeeded];
});
```